# Android Scrollable Tabs + Swipe state when swiping

Tags: java, android, android-viewpager, swipe, android-tabs

I'm trying to make an application with multiple Tabs. For each tab I'm using different fragments. And when I leaf through tabs the information in them is changing.

How can I save the state of each tab when swiping?

Code for example:

**MainActivity.java**:

```
package com.tabs.example;

import java.util.Locale;

import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.PagerTabStrip;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;
    ViewPager            mViewPager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

        PagerTabStrip pagerTabStrip = (PagerTabStrip) findViewById(R.id.pager_tab_strip);
        pagerTabStrip.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
        pagerTabStrip.setTabIndicatorColor(Color.CYAN);
        pagerTabStrip.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
    }

    public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {

            Fragment fragment;
            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    fragment = new Fragment1();
                    break;
                case 1:
                    fragment = new Fragment2();
                    break;
                case 2:
                    fragment = new Fragment3();
                    break;
                default:
                    fragment  = null;
                    break;
            }
            return fragment;

        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return 3;
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            Locale l = Locale.getDefault();
            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    return getString(R.string.title_section1).toUpperCase(l);
                case 1:
                    return getString(R.string.title_section2).toUpperCase(l);
                case 2:
                    return getString(R.string.title_section3).toUpperCase(l);
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

**Fragment1.java**:

```
package com.tabs.example;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

public class Fragment1 extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment1, container, false);

        DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
        Date date = new Date();
        String time = dateFormat.format(date);

        TextView tv1 = (TextView) root.findViewById(R.id.tv1);
        tv1.setText(time);

        return root;

    }
}
```

**Fragment2.java**:

```
package com.tabs.example;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

public class Fragment2 extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment2, container, false);

        DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
        Date date = new Date();
        String time = dateFormat.format(date);

        TextView tv2 = (TextView) root.findViewById(R.id.tv2);
        tv2.setText(time);

        return root;

    }
}
```

**Fragment3.java**:

```
package com.tabs.example;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

public class Fragment3 extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment3, container, false);

        DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
        Date date = new Date();
        String time = dateFormat.format(date);

        TextView tv3 = (TextView) root.findViewById(R.id.tv3);
        tv1.setText(time);

        return root;

    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by saving the state? You can cache them all by setting the ViewPagerAdapter like this: mViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(3);

Comment: I want to when swiping to the third tab and back to the first time was held and there, and there. And when you change the screen orientation, too, everything remained as it was before the change.
May be I want to very much?)))

Comment: mViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(3); I will try later, Thanks you

Comment: Yes, if you set off page limit to include all your tabs, lets say they are a list, and you swipe down the list, and you come back to it, the position will still remain

Comment: wangyif2, thanks you! It's work. How can I tell you "thank you"? Add reply and I accepted his and make helpful

Comment: I changed the comment to answer, you can accept the answer =)

Comment: This really helped me learn to launch fragments through my viewpager. Thank you very much!

Comment: I wants to add header section above tabs, what should I do for this?

Comment: @Araju, what do you mean? Custom ActionBar or custom header between ActionBar and Tabs?

Comment: @Timofey Dmitriev - I have got the solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can cache them all by setting the ViewPagerAdapter like this:

```
mViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(3);
```

Comment: I wants to add header section above tabs, what should I do for this?